# How to create directory in resource directory in install 4j

Tags: install4j

How to create directory in resource directory in Install4j or is there is any way to add folder in resource directory or user folder of resource directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the files that are added under Installer->Custom code  & Resources, there is no way to create a directory structure there as of install4j 8.